# how to distribute an amount across varioius product based on number of acvtive customer in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I am $10000 and I want distribute that among 3 products so that the sum of individual amount would be exact $10000.

Product dataframe

```
product_name active_subscription
Prod1        20
Prod2        30
PROD3        80
```

So individual amount would be:

```
Prod1=10000*20/(20+50+80)
Prod2=10000*50/(20+50+80)
Prod3=10000*80/(20+50+80)
```

How can I implement this using pandas in most efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"product_name ": ["Prod1", "Prdo2","Prod3"],
                   "active_subscription": [20, 50, 80]})
df["distributed"] = df.active_subscription * 10000 / df.active_subscription.sum(axis=0)
df
```

Result:

[image]

```
df.distributed.sum(axis=0)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I make sure there sum of distributed cost would be exact $10000 ?

Comment: use `df.sitibuted.sum(axis=0)` gives 10000